# Can we Encrypt Stored procedures in snowflakes similar to what we do in SQL Server?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Can we encrypt stored procedures in Snowflake similar to what we do in SQL Server?

For example, similar to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #EncryptSP
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
QUERY HERE
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Snowflake databases is encrypted, so I believe the issue is allowing users to run a stored procedure but not see its contents. That's not a problem.

```
-- Using a database called TEST
grant usage on database test to role public;
grant usage on schema public to role public;

-- Create a secure procedure and run it as SYSADMIN (or whatever role you want)
create or replace secure procedure test.public.hello_world()
returns string
language JavaScript
execute as owner
as
$$

    return "Hello world";

$$;

-- Allow users in the PUBLIC role to run the procedure
grant usage on procedure HELLO_WORLD() to role PUBLIC;

-- Test that users in role PUBLIC can run the procedure
use role public;
use database test;
use schema public;
call HELLO_WORLD();

-- However, they cannot see the stored procedure
select get_ddl('procedure', 'HELLO_WORLD()');

-- The owner can.
use role SYSADMIN;
select get_ddl('procedure', 'HELLO_WORLD()');
```

Comment: Hi Greg,  thanks for your answer. It seems logical. I wanted the user to use stored procedure but not see its content as you pointed out. So, only with admin role we can do this or can we create custom roles as well?

Comment: You can do it with custom roles too.

Comment: Thanks Greg! Appreciate your prompt responses.